# What is "member" and why does it expect to find an `org` directory in my home directory?

Tags: spacemacs, debugging

Faced with some org-agenda problems, I tried this:

- Blow away all emacs config that I know about

  - .emacs
  - .emacs.d
  - .spacemacs
  - .spacemacs.d
- Follow spacemacs install docs from scratch (checking out clean spacemacs repository at revision f5489758)
- Restart emacs after the installation

I got this in `*Messages*`:

```
Loading /home/me/.spacemacs...done
(Spacemacs) Warning: Cannot find any of the specified fonts (Source Code Pro)! Font settings may not be correct.
Spacemacs is ready.
Loading /home/me/.emacs.d/.cache/recentf...done
member: Opening directory: Not a directory, /home/me/org
Package cl is deprecated
```

I didn't expect the message `member: Opening directory: Not a directory, /home/me/org`

`emacs --debug-on-init` does not land me in the debugger.

What is "member" and why is it expecting to find that directory?

Comment: I had a file /home/me/org which contained some lisp code.  Perhaps removing that will fix my issues, but I'm still very interested in answers to this question!

Comment: What is the setting of `org-agenda-files`? And the option is `--debug-init`. Do you have a separate customization file?

Comment: Try to reproduce starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Explicitly load whatever is necessary to repro the problem, using `load-library`, `require`, or `load-file` (put whatever you need in your `load-path`, for the first two). IOW, remove everything that's not relevant to reproducing the problem.

Comment: Removing the lisp file at /home/me/org did fix my issues, but I still am very curious what the "member:" in `*Messages*` means.  I approve of your advice Drew, though I've found following it is somewhat hindered by the complicated configuration of spacemacs: it does things at startup involving updating packages etc. before any of one's own startup code executes.  I suspect it was hitting an error during byte compliation for some reason, which would leave org not fully byte-compiled.

Comment: Spacemacs comes with a *lot* of customization, and making a minimal working example of any particular problem is quite challenging. This also makes it very difficult for expert Emacsers who don't use Spacemacs to help with Spacemacs problems. You might have better luck looking for help directly from spacemacs devs: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues

Comment: Hi, there is a recently fix about this https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/15367, maybe you can try to update to the newest develop commit.

Comment: @TianshuWang thanks, though it's not obvious to me how this is related (not saying it's not).
Separately: it occurred to me that `member` in the error message I saw refers to the function of that name.  But why would function `member` try to "open" a directory?